# Make dict by a column dataframe and not erase equal keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
matrix_cadeia[1] = matrix_cadeia[1].astype('int64').mul(matrix_cadeia["quant"], fill_value=0)
matrix_cadeia[3] = matrix_cadeia[3].astype('int64').mul(matrix_cadeia["quant"], fill_value=0)

Cadeias_1 = dict(zip(matrix_cadeia[0], matrix_cadeia[1]))
Cadeias_2 = dict(zip(matrix_cadeia[2], matrix_cadeia[3]))

print("\n", matrix_cadeia)
print("\n", Cadeias_1)
```

Matrix Cadeia:

```
            0    1    2   3  quant
PORTICO   IAC   24  IJC  10      2
JJAT      IAC   72    0   0      6
JJEL     IABB  720    0   0    144
JJAA      IAC  144  IJC  60     12
JJSP      IAC   48  IJC  20      4
JJSL      IAC   36  IJC  15      3
```

Current Output:

```
 {'IAC': 36, 'IABB': 720}
```

It erases the other "IAC" keys and gives only the last row. Anyone know a way to convert it to dict summing the values of the keys rows?

I want that output for Cadeias_1 to be:

```
{'IAC': 324, 'IABB': 720}
```

and then I want do the same for Cadeias_2.

Comment: Dicts cannot have duplicate keys. There's likely a way to solve this without ziping and converting to a dict. Could you include a sample of your source dataframe/matrix and your expected output?

Comment: But it is there, the source is the matrix and the expected output is the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) and [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-sum) can be used for each pair of columns:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({0: {'PORTICO': 'IAC', 'JJAT': 'IAC',
                       'JJEL': 'IABB', 'JJAA': 'IAC',
                       'JJSP': 'IAC', 'JJSL': 'IAC'},
                   1: {'PORTICO': 24, 'JJAT': 72,
                       'JJEL': 720, 'JJAA': 144,
                       'JJSP': 48, 'JJSL': 36},
                   2: {'PORTICO': 'IJC', 'JJAT': '0',
                       'JJEL': '0', 'JJAA': 'IJC',
                       'JJSP': 'IJC', 'JJSL': 'IJC'},
                   3: {'PORTICO': 10, 'JJAT': 0,
                       'JJEL': 0, 'JJAA': 60,
                       'JJSP': 20, 'JJSL': 15},
                   'quant': {'PORTICO': 2, 'JJAT': 6,
                             'JJEL': 144, 'JJAA': 12,
                             'JJSP': 4, 'JJSL': 3}})

Cadeias_1 = df[[0, 1]].groupby(0).sum()[1].to_dict()
Cadeias_2 = df[[2, 3]].groupby(2).sum()[3].to_dict()

# For Display
print(Cadeias_1)
print(Cadeias_2)
```

Cadeias_1

```
{'IABB': 720, 'IAC': 324}
```

Cadeias_2

```
{'0': 0, 'IJC': 105}
```